# Append each line with comma and label

Tags: python

I am writing a script in python to write a new line and then append the line with a comma and a string label. Here is the piece of code.

```
new = open(newpath + "/" + "train" + ".txt", 'w')

for idx, tr in enumerate(train_data):
    new.write(train_data[idx] + ' , '  + str(index)
```

Output is as follow

```
Recommendations, thoughts, tips and tricks, or peanuts on moving from wordpress to django
 , 1Wordpress [caption] processing
 , 1Wordpress: query all images in a posts media library
```

comma and label is appended to the line but it moves it to the next line.

I need it as follow:

```
Recommendations, thoughts, tips and tricks, or peanuts on moving from wordpress to django , 1
Wordpress [caption] processing , 1
Wordpress: query all images in a posts media library , 1
```

Comment: can you `print(repr(train_data[idx]))` and see if there's a `\n` character at the end of it ?

Comment: yeah, thanks for the tip, there is a new line in `train_data` @MooingRawr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of what you have provided, your train data contains a `'\n'` character. So I would recommend that you use `str.strip` to remove any trailing white space and new line characters.

```
for idx, tr in enumerate(train_data):
    new.write(train_data[idx].strip() + ' , '  + str(index))
```

I'm not sure where `index` came from so I left it in. You also don't have to index your data as you can just iterate over it.

```
for tr in train_data:
    new.write(tr.strip() + ' , '  + str(index))
```

Comment: `for idx, tr in enumerate(train_data):
    new.write(train_data[idx].strip() + ' , '  + str(index))` that was exactly what I did :)